# Occasional Protobuf.net Exception - Timeout while inspecting metadata

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

On rare occasions I've got the Timeout while inspecting metadata exception.
I've only seen it when the server RAM is at 95%, CPU more than 70% and even then it's impossible to reproduce it. Also it was reported only when serializing a List<OrderLine> instance, where OrderLine is:

```
[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class OrderLine {

    public OrderLine() { }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public decimal ID { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public double Qty { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public DateTime When { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public OrderTypes OrderType { get; set; }
}
```

OrderTypes is an enum.

I'm using protobuf-net to serialize and later persist .net instances to a SQLServer database. It's done asynchronously with several threads working in parallel.

I've read here that precompiling the serializers at startup helps or avoids this exception. Here’s a short snippet that runs at startup:

```
    static object mysync = new object();
    static ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel protobufmodel = null;
    ...
    lock (mysync) {
        var pbtypes = new Type[] {
            ... several other types but no Orderline ...
            typeof(List<OrderLine>),
        };
        protobufmodel = ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Create();
        pbtypes.Select(t => protobufmodel.Add(t, true));
        protobufmodel.CompileInPlace();
    }
```

My question: Should I also add the type OrderLine to the model (i.e., to the pbtypes array)? Would that help? Or is it enough for CompileInPlace to have List<OrderLine> ?

Comment: You realize that `.Select` *doesn't actually do anything* unless you iterate it, right?

Comment: Ah. Ups. Shame on me. That's it. I was iterating over it, but after the call of CompileInPlace()! I've probably rearranged the code without noticing that I was screwing it up.